# How would one go about adding an ordering system to a restaurant website? (react)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, e-commerce

I'm currently building out a react site for my portfolio, I'm considering adding a way to order online and was wondering how I might go about that. The answers I've gotten on google haven't really satisfied me.

Answer (score 0):

This question is super broad. Broadly, you would have some sort of form that would get order details and accept payment, then send a request to the backend API, which would send the orders to the restaurant, then send a success message and any confirmation/tracking info to the frontend